# WP_Http::request seem to have a request size limit

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WordPress on nginx my post_max_size is 100M however i'm trying to send an array of 100 items and I get 22 items on the other service, I double checked `WP_Http::request` documentation and I can't find anything, can anyone think what could that be?

NOTE: I tested the same endpoint using postman with the 100 items and the backend works fine. the problem is from the WordPress side